# Filtered JSON arrays to push into one array?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to filter cars in one array. So in html code, there are a lot of checkboxes. If I check the gasoline checkbox, then in the filtered array should be only the cars with gasoline, when I check the doors4 checkbox, in the filtered array should be the gasoline cars with 4 doors. etc. So how can I resolve this?
Between I try to make the same as this one here: https://www.kia.com/de/modelle/entdecken-sie-die-kia-modelle/ - when you click on the big black button, then there will be a filter.

I know how to filter it by Key-value, but that's it, I don't know what should be the next step.

```
let engineDiesel = cars.filter(model => model.engine === 'diesel');
let engineGasoline = cars.filter(model => model.engine === 'gasoline');
```

```
{
    "models": [
        {
            "name": "Kia Picanto",
            "category": "kompakt",
            "image": "picanto.png",
            "price": 10750,
            "monthlyPrice": 122,
            "engine": "gasoline",
            "doors": 4,
            "seats": 4,
            "drive": "2wd",
            "transmission": "manual",
            "efficiency": "c"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kia Rio",
            "category": "kompakt",
            "image": "rio.png",
            "price": 14590,
            "monthlyPrice": 147,
            "engine": "hybrid",
            "doors": 5,
            "seats": 5,
            "drive": "4wd",
            "transmission": "automatic",
            "efficiency": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kia Stonic",
            "category": "suv",
            "image": "stonic.png",
            "price": 16650,
            "monthlyPrice": 177,
            "engine": "diesel",
            "doors": 5,
            "seats": 4,
            "drive": "2wd",
            "transmission": "automatic",
            "efficiency": "d"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kia e-Soul",
            "category": "limusine",
            "image": "e-Soul",
            "price": 37590,
            "monthlyPrice": 291,
            "engine": "electro",
            "doors": 4,
            "seats": 4,
            "drive": "4wd",
            "transmission": "manual",
            "efficiency": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kia Ceed",
            "category": "gt",
            "image": "ceed.png",
            "price": 16990,
            "monthlyPrice": 127,
            "engine": "gasoline",
            "doors": 5,
            "seats": 5,
            "drive": "2wd",
            "transmission": "manual",
            "efficiency": "a"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use Array.prototype.every on an object with the conditions you want

```js
const data = {
  "models": [{
      "name": "Kia Picanto",
      "category": "kompakt",
      "image": "picanto.png",
      "price": 10750,
      "monthlyPrice": 122,
      "engine": "gasoline",
      "doors": 4,
      "seats": 4,
      "drive": "2wd",
      "transmission": "manual",
      "efficiency": "c"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kia Rio",
      "category": "kompakt",
      "image": "rio.png",
      "price": 14590,
      "monthlyPrice": 147,
      "engine": "hybrid",
      "doors": 5,
      "seats": 5,
      "drive": "4wd",
      "transmission": "automatic",
      "efficiency": "a"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kia Stonic",
      "category": "suv",
      "image": "stonic.png",
      "price": 16650,
      "monthlyPrice": 177,
      "engine": "diesel",
      "doors": 5,
      "seats": 4,
      "drive": "2wd",
      "transmission": "automatic",
      "efficiency": "d"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kia e-Soul",
      "category": "limusine",
      "image": "e-Soul",
      "price": 37590,
      "monthlyPrice": 291,
      "engine": "electro",
      "doors": 4,
      "seats": 4,
      "drive": "4wd",
      "transmission": "manual",
      "efficiency": "a"
    },
    {
      "name": "Kia Ceed",
      "category": "gt",
      "image": "ceed.png",
      "price": 16990,
      "monthlyPrice": 127,
      "engine": "gasoline",
      "doors": 5,
      "seats": 5,
      "drive": "2wd",
      "transmission": "manual",
      "efficiency": "a"
    }
  ]
}


const query = {
  engine: x => x === "gasoline" || x === "diesel",
  doors: 4,
  price: x => x > 1000
}

const result = data.models.filter(car => Object.entries(query).every(([key, value]) =>
  (typeof value === "function") ? value(car[key]) : (car[key] === value)
))

console.log(result)
```

Comment: But what if I need also the diesel cars with 4 doors? I can't write like const query = {
  engine: "gasoline",engine: "gasoline",
  doors: 4
}

Comment: @venndi I've modified my answer to allow the conditions to be functions. I hope it's clear

Comment: ahh okay, I see you have changed your code... I'll try it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A filter returns an array, so you can always just chain filters if that works best for your solution.

```js
const cars = {
    "models": [
        {
            "name": "Kia Picanto",
            "category": "kompakt",
            "image": "picanto.png",
            "price": 10750,
            "monthlyPrice": 122,
            "engine": "gasoline",
            "doors": 4,
            "seats": 4,
            "drive": "2wd",
            "transmission": "manual",
            "efficiency": "c"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kia Rio",
            "category": "kompakt",
            "image": "rio.png",
            "price": 14590,
            "monthlyPrice": 147,
            "engine": "hybrid",
            "doors": 5,
            "seats": 5,
            "drive": "4wd",
            "transmission": "automatic",
            "efficiency": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kia Stonic",
            "category": "suv",
            "image": "stonic.png",
            "price": 16650,
            "monthlyPrice": 177,
            "engine": "diesel",
            "doors": 5,
            "seats": 4,
            "drive": "2wd",
            "transmission": "automatic",
            "efficiency": "d"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kia e-Soul",
            "category": "limusine",
            "image": "e-Soul",
            "price": 37590,
            "monthlyPrice": 291,
            "engine": "electro",
            "doors": 4,
            "seats": 4,
            "drive": "4wd",
            "transmission": "manual",
            "efficiency": "a"
        },
        {
            "name": "Kia Ceed",
            "category": "gt",
            "image": "ceed.png",
            "price": 16990,
            "monthlyPrice": 127,
            "engine": "gasoline",
            "doors": 5,
            "seats": 5,
            "drive": "2wd",
            "transmission": "manual",
            "efficiency": "a"
        }
    ]
}

let engineGasolineWithFourDoors = cars.models
    .filter(model => model.engine === 'gasoline')
    .filter(model => model.doors === 4)

console.log(engineGasolineWithFourDoors);
```

Comment: There would be a million variations...it's impossible to make it in that way. There is some 40 checkboxes.

Comment: traversing the array multiple times is not ideal either

Comment: Then the other answer from bel3atar is better. Have a change event listener on each checkbox, which looks at the value of your checkboxes to build the query object. Then bel3atar's answer does everything you need from there.